# Telnet doesn't keep its connection

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, telnet

I've installed XAMPP on windows 10 using "xampp-win32-7.1.12-0-VC14-installer". MySQL/MariaDB Server works and "http://localhost/phpmyadmin" is reachable, but:

(1) when calling "telnet -l root localhost or [ip]  3306", this message is gotten "Y
 5.5.5-10.1.29-MariaDB[>bSW>o?áabI),DO@4"L9mysql_native_password". And after some seconds the message "Verbindung zu Host verloren" [lost connection to host].

(2) when calling "http://localhost:3306[/test]", browser Edge produces the following text 
"Y 5.5.5-10.1.29-MariaDBy^LBEs7Sÿ÷? }?]9D,Jqy0~Mmysql_native_password!ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order" 
and Chrome this text "This page isn’t working, localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE"

It shows the version 10.1.29-MariaDB, when a MySQL client is called. 
Windows firewall doesn't block any connection to port 3306 (logging file is checked).

In comparison with HTTP Server I think MySQL Server isn't completely set up. Any ideas to fix these two problems. Thank you.

Comment: Use the mysqlclient to connect to the darabase.

Comment: Like: mysql -h hostname -u username -p       then the client asked for the password

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27266/connection-to-host-lost-using-telnet-to-mysql